# how do i use "as" in this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

here

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM
  tbl_department 
  RIGHT JOIN tbl_video 
    ON tbl_video.department_id = tbl_department.department_id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_language 
    ON tbl_language.language_id = tbl_video.video_language 
WHERE tbl_video.department_id LIKE '%1%'
```

i already tried

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM
  tbl_department 
  RIGHT JOIN tbl_video 
    ON tbl_video.department_id = tbl_department.department_id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_language 
    ON tbl_language.language_id = tbl_video.video_language AS numbers 
WHERE tbl_video.department_id LIKE '%1%'
```

but it doesnt work.
help pls.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Although we could guess, we don't know what you're trying to do, nor why you think a simple google search won't help you.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:sql-server] as well as [tag:mysql] - are you working with both database systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use (*) it implies all columns , "AS" can be used for one column , so column from a table tbl_department with an one column .

Answer (score 2):

Use as in select
i.e

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*)  AS numbers
.....
```

Dont use AS somewhere..Use it in select

Comment: I would personally also use [an implicit] `as` in the introduced relationships .. but `as` is generally *required* with aggregate functions in the output clause (although I think some providers will implicitly assume the aggregate name ..).

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT 
 COUNT(*) as total_records
 FROM
 tbl_department 
 RIGHT JOIN tbl_video 
 ON tbl_video.department_id = tbl_department.department_id 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_language 
 ON tbl_language.language_id = tbl_video.video_language 
 WHERE tbl_video.department_id LIKE '%1%';
```

This will show you count of all selected records.

Comment: That `AS` at the end of the `ON` of a `JOIN` is still incorrect.

Comment: There is no need to add AS. Because all column names are different.

Comment: I'm pointing out that the second to last line of code in your answer has an `AS` that is still an error, as in the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Numbers FROM ...
                ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can give aliases also the table names so it will ease in the join clause,
something like this:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) as total_records
FROM
tbl_department as td --the word 'as' is not mandatory , you can just directly give it an alias
RIGHT JOIN tbl_video as tv
ON tv.department_id = td.department_id -- using the aliases
LEFT JOIN tbl_language as tl -- using the aliases
ON tl.language_id = tv.video_language -- using the aliases
WHERE tv.department_id LIKE '%1%';
```

BTW, the best practice is to use "left join"
so you can arrange the order of the tables you're joining together

see example:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) as total_records
FROM tbl_video as tv
LEFT JOIN  tbl_department as td 
ON tv.department_id = td.department_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_language as tl 
ON tl.language_id = tv.video_language 
WHERE tv.department_id LIKE '%1%';
```